# Yii 2 двуколочный стиль

Tags: yii2

Не увидел во второй версии layout подключаемых в контролере, и вроде как не могу отнаследовать от общего шаблона.

А хочу сделать двуколочный макет

```
    #leftcol { /* Левая колонка */
        float: left; /* Обтекание справа */
        width: 20%; /* Ширина колонки */
    }
    #rightcol { /* Правая колонка */
        margin-left: 21%; /* Отступ слева */
    }
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

каким образом решается эта проблема?

Comment: двуколочный? двуколочноый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно создать свой `layout`, который хочешь использовать и подключать его тогда, когда захочешь.

например в контроллере:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller {
    public $layout = 'column2';
    // ...
}
```

в экшне:

```
public function actionYourAction($id) {
    $this->layout = 'yourNewLayout';

    return $this->render('yourView', [
        'model' =>$model,
    ]);
}
```

во `view` (если я не ошибаюсь) так:

`$this->context->layout = 'your-layout';`

...

или установив на всё приложение глобально в конфиге:

```
...
$config = [
     'layout' => 'yourLayout',
...
```

Comment: точно с первой версией не путаете? потому что yii2lesson\views\layouts это https://gist.github.com/des1roer/b90c599a4a62adac9096

Comment: @des1roer Во-первых - я не понял к чему ваша ссылка и что я там должен был разглядеть или понять))) А во-вторых - прежде чем написать ответ, я у себя все проверил. Благо у меня установлен проект на `yii2` который могу помучить. Либо я не понял, что вам надо)

Comment: я про то что в папке \views\layouts лежит единственный файл main.php без стилей и верстки. и ни в одном контролере не вижу чтобы подключался layout. можете привести минимально рабочее решение?

Comment: а понял вашу мысль. увидел <div id="container">. странно что сразу в глаза не бросилось

Comment: @des1roer вообще по дефолту этот самый `main` прописан непосредственно в ядре фреймворка.. если интересно вот тут: `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php` Там вообще много чего завязано. Например генерирование шаблона в  `gii` генераторе, тоже ссылаются на `main` и  виджеты и прочее. Все они по дефолту в ядре нарисованы. Поэтому только вот так переопределять.... Либо на свой страх и риск менять в ядре)))